# Password Hashing API Query

Tags: php, mysql, hash, bcrypt, php-password-hash

So I'm using the new PHP 5.5 Password Hashing API, and I'm not sure if I got this correctly.

I've tried automatically rehashing every login and sometimes I fail, even when the hashing turns out to be the same anyways, I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

It could be the query function that I probably got wrong, because the hashes don't even change when I check phpMyAdmin.

```
if (password_needs_rehash($result_row->user_password_hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT))
{
    $newhash = password_hash(
        $_POST['user_password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, 
        ['cost' => 12, 'salt' => 'superfreakingsonicdude',]
    );

    // update hash in database
    $this->connection->query(
        "UPDATE users SET user_password_hash='" . $newhash .  
        "' WHERE user_name='".$result_row->user_name."'"
    );
}
```

[Here is where you can find all the functions.](https://github.com/MrXXIV/PHP-5.5-login/blob/master/app/Login/Classes/login.class.php)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're checking if it's hashed by `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`, and if it's not, you'll save a hash using `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`. If they're not the same (for example, if newer version of PHP set `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` to `PASSWORD_ROT13`), you'll _always_ rehash the password since it's never hashed using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`.

Comment: (in short, use `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` _or_ `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`, don't mix them)

Comment: I realized that, the original hash was BCRYPT so I do need to set to that.

The main problem is that the hash doesn't change regardless.

Comment: Why are you defining your own salt? You should use a generated salt instead of the weak salt you have there.

Comment: Btw, what does "sometimes I fail" mean?

Comment: This isn't for commercial use, so I'm not exactly making an important salt. This is in my [**Github project**](https://github.com/MrXXIV/PHP-5.5-login).

What I said there was a misstatement.

Comment: @TerryCampbell it doesn't matter if it's for commercial use or not. Don't pass a static salt. Ever. Let it generate a random one for you, don't pass the salt parameter. Also, don't change the hash every login, that's just bad. Change it when you change the algorithm or cost, or when the user changes their password. But there's no reason to change it on every login...

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Answer (score 4):

The funcion [`password_needs_rehash`](http://php.net/password_needs_rehash) has been introduced to check if you need to upgrade:

```
password_needs_rehash($result_row->user_password_hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

> This function checks to see if the supplied hash implements the algorithm and options provided. If not, it is assumed that the hash needs to be rehashed.

If you have problems to understand what this function does, the RFC contains the function in PHP code. So if you can read PHP code, you should be able to read the following (see the part introduced as *It could be implemented in user-land by:*): https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash#password_needs_rehash

Makes sense to test if the hash in the database (store) is of the same algorithm as in `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` or not. That means to check if `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` has been changed between the time the hash has been stored last time and now.

Right now `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` *is* `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` so it should always return false. In your case it returns true, because you're testing without your password options.

Change that and you should be fine:

```
$options = ['cost' => 12, 'salt' => 'superfreakingsonicdude',];
########

if (password_needs_rehash($result_row->user_password_hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options))
                                                                             ########
{
    $newhash = password_hash($_POST['user_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
                                                      ################  ########

    // update hash in database
    $this->connection->query(
        "UPDATE users SET user_password_hash='" . $newhash .
            "' WHERE user_name='".$result_row->user_name."'"
    );
}
```

Also consider to continue to use `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` if you want to benefit from a default hashing algo update in PHP core.

Comment: The user_password_hash still doesn't change. Unless..does it require the salt to be generated in order for the rehash function to react?

Comment: The `user_password_hash()` return value won't change unless you have changed (at least one of) those three parameter: 1.) the plain (the password), 2.) the *concrete* algo (`PASSWORD_DEFAULT` is not concrete over time) and 3.) the options. Unless none of these changes, the hash will be the same (which is the distinct nature of a hash function by the way).

Comment: Ahh okay! I was more of hoping to have the whole hash change every time the person log ins as long as it can still be read, but I'm guessing that wouldn't make any sense to.

Answer (score 3):

The input to the hash is the password and salt. Same password, same salt, same result.
If you leave the `salt` parameter out, a random salt will be generated each time and you should get a different result. You should not provide a static salt. This means all users have the same salt, which greatly diminishes its effectiveness. Each individual hash <strike>needs</strike> should have a random salt.

Comment: But the problem is, I'm not getting a different generation at all when I try to query a rehash.

Comment: Link: [Here is where you can find all the functions.](https://github.com/MrXXIV/PHP-5.5-login/blob/master/app/Login/Classes/login.class.php)